# Flutter iOS: How can I keep my application sending location to server continuously when state is inactive?

Tags: ios, flutter, location, client

I need to have my application to send location to server even if the state is inactive. On Android, this works for a long time. On iOS, the application keeps sending location for around 30 seconds after it stops sending it. The background is still sent when the application is in background but it does not keep the application "alive" or "active". Can I wake up the app on for a certain time interval so the location is sent?

Comment: You need to enable background location mode in your iOS app and have "always" location permission

Comment: I have done all those, but the sending stops after 30 seconds. I would need to keep my application sending the location even when the state is inactive.

Comment: It is important that your app sends the data in response to the call to the location delegate at the native layer. You cannot rely on a timer in flutter